# Get Target Number Using Number List and Arithmetic Operations

Tags: c++, expression, dynamic-programming

I have 2 inputs:

- S[] = list of numbers
- Target value

> S{2,9}
>
> Target Value = 729

I want to find an arithmatic operation using these given number which can generate target value. We can use any number as many times as we want. Only Sum and Multiplication operation is allowed.

For ex.: 9*9*9 = 729

Also, We can use combination of numbers.

> For Ex:
>
> S{2,9}
>
> target value = 49

So solution can be:

> 2+9+9+29 = 49

I want to use Dynamic Programmming approch for this using C++.

Comment: And your problem is?

Comment: I want to know the logic to build this program.

Comment: Do you have no idea how to do it at all except for using dynamic programming?

Comment: No I don't have any idea about it.

Comment: do you have solution without dynamic programming?

Comment: No. Is this homework for a class? If it is, you should ask your instructor.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Thinking this algorithm.

```
1. make all numbers using that digit set. {2, 9} 
target=729 n = digit set numers

-make numbers that mixed by the digits lower than target, 
and duplicable. 

digit length1 ; n count ; 2, 9 
digit length2 ; n*n count ; 22, 29, 92, 99 
digit length3 ; n*n*n count ; 222, 229, 292, 299,  922, 929, 992, 999 
(remove bigger than 729) 
digit length 4 ; no more find. target length is 3.

-make new number set by upper found numbers 
2, 9,  22, 29, 92, 99 222, 229, 292, 299 
m = # of upper set. 
o = 2 (# of operators)

-and operation case... use operator plus and multiply.

2. make operation set. 

use 1 node ; check the upper elements is equal to target 
m cases

use 2 node ;  pick 2 elements. and select operator. 
 1 operator use. 
m*m * o cases

use 3 node ; pick 3 elements. and select operator. 
 2 operator use. 
m*m*m * o*o cases

and so on.

but how many times doing this? 
in worse case, 
if the number set has 1. 
1+1+1+...=target(729 times)
And this problem... 1*1*1*... infinite case...
1*9*9*9, 1*1*1*9*9*9, 1*...*1*9*9*9, ...
```

Some restrictions are needed. and more efficient algorithm is needed.

Comment: Can you give me basic c++ code for that? I am already thought of this logic but not able to develop proper program.

Comment: @GauravParvadiya Why are you not able to code it? Be more specific. Show what you tried and a specific problem you have. You should at least be able to code part of it.